# How to call a public void which has a JFrame

Tags: java, jframe

Basically I have this code

```
public void Start(JFrame frame1){
    frame1.setSize(1000,1000);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

So how would another public void for example

```
public void main1(){
```

Call Start as

```
Start()
```

doesn’t work it says you need JFrame which means I have to add

```
(JFrame frame1)
```

to each public void so I thought there must be another way. Thank you

---

Run

```
public void start(JFrame frame1){
```

From

```
public void main1(){
```

I decided to just extend JFrame at the start the just add things after so then I could call public voids and things –

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly ?

Comment: Run public void start(JFrame frame1){     From       public void main1(){

Comment: The context is not clear - post more code.

Comment: @Callum: @Arnaud's question is more "what problem are you trying to solve?" because as it stands, the answer to your question may very well be "declare a `JFrame` inside `main1` as `whatever` and call `Start(whatever)`"

Comment: The method `Start` requires a reference to a JFrame, since it needs to know what JFrame to do the `setSize()` etc.. on.  So you can't just call `Start()` without passing a JFrame to it.

Comment: I decided to just extend JFrame at the start the just add things after so then I could call public voids and things

Comment: @Callum please extend your code example and the description. At the moment its not very clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of adding comments. That way you can format as needed and everything is in one place. Comments may or may not be shown initially. Make it easy for people to help you. You may also want to take the [tour] to understand how to ask a good question and hence get good answers.

Comment: Copied comments to question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a `JFrame` object to the method `start(JFrame frame1)`. Otherwise you could remove the parameter from `start ()` and use a global variable inside this method in order to access a `JFrame`. But in my opinion that wouldn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with methods in Java. The method `calculate` calls `doAdd` and `doSubtract`; note the `doAdd` is called with method arguments `i` and `j`. In general:

- A method is called with arguments `i` and `j`: `doAdd(i, j);`
- A method defines parameters `m` and `n`: `public void doAdd(int m, int n) {...`

Example code:

```
public class Testing {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Testing app = new Testing();
        app.calculate(12, 3, "+");
        app.claculate(34, 9, "-");
    }

    public void calculate(int j, int j, String operator) {

        if (operator.equals("+")) {
            doAdd(i, j);
        }
        else if (operator.equals("-")) {
            doSubtract(i, j);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Not interested in other operations!");
        }
    }

    public void doAdd(int m, int n) {
        int result = m + n;
        System.out.println("Result of " + m + " plus " + n + " = " + result);
    }

    public void doSubtract(int m, int n) {
        int result = m - n;
        System.out.println("Result of " + m + " minus " + n + " = " + result);
    }
}
```